Can't change default app, "not enough information available"
I am attempting to change the default text editor on my Mac from TextEdit to Smultron. I...

selected a text file that was opening in TextEdit
Get Info
popped-up Open With and selected Smultron
clicked Change All

This results in an alert asking if I'm sure, I click Continue.
That results in a second alert:

An error occurred while changing the application that opens “kuvi 2”
because not enough information is available.

I cannot find anything about this online, any ideas?

Similar to those? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259119/error-while-changing-the-default-application-with-which-we-open-a-file https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315608/how-to-set-the-default-editor-for-a-makefile

I use the following prefpane for files with a uniform-type-identifier like "public.data": https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

@Redarm - I'm going to say no, because the files in question were all created by me. The only thing that has changed is the actual computer, I upgraded my 2013 Mac Pro to a Mac Studio.
